# MooTools: Events

Tags: json, mootools

Let's save I have an Element:

```
var el = $('mooo');
```

What's the easiest way to set its '`onclick`' attribute or event (it may already have one)?

Answer (score 4):

MooTools handles all its event adding with the [addEvent()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:addEvent) function:

```
var el = $('mooo');
el.addEvent('click',function(){ alert("I got clicked!"); });
```

Event names simply have the "on" prefix removed, ie. 'click','mouseover','mouseenter', etc.

Comment: yop, if JamesBrownlsDead wants to get rid of the events and replace them he should do like that : http://jsfiddle.net/WqgJE/ (maybe that's why he mentioned that the element may already have one?)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('mooo').addEvent('click', function(e){
    // your code here.
    e.stop();
});
```

You mention, regarding events, that your element `mooo` may already have one. This should not affect this code.